# how can i loop thorugh an array of objects?

Tags: javascript

How can I loop through an array of objects?

```
users = new Array()
users.push({id: "5", name: "solomom"});
users.push({id: "3", name: "jonathan"});
for(u in users){
    alert(u.name);
}
```

This alerts me with undefined, am I doing something wrong? 
im really a big newbie in javascript.

Comment: Try doing `console.log(u)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing it to:

```
alert(users[u].name);
```

Would make it alert expected values, because [for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loops iterate through the keys of an object, however you should not use `for in` loops to iterate through arrays in Javascript.

Instead use a regular for loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
    alert(users[i].name);
}
```

You should also get in the habit of using `console.log` to debug rather than `alert`. It will make debugging much easier when you need it to be.

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking of [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

Syntax

```
for (variable of object)
  statement
```

Parameters

- `variable` - On each iteration a value of a different property is assigned to variable.
- `object` - Object whose enumerable properties are iterated.

This isn't supported in most modern browsers.

---

You'd probably want to use `Array.forEach` for what you're trying to accomplish.

```
users.forEach(function(u) {
    alert(u.name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a regular for loop to loop through arrays. A `for-in` loop iterates the enumerable properties of an object. An array in JavaScript is technically an object, which is where the problem comes from.

```
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; ++i)
{
    alert( users[i].name );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `for..in` loop assigns each *key* to `u`, not each value. You would need to do something like
`alert(users[u].name)`

That being said, NEVER use `for..in` on an array (unless it's sparse). Instead, do this:

```
for( i=0, l=users.length; i<l; i++) {
    alert(users[i].name);
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why `for..in` is bad practice?

Comment: @Wex: This SO has good info on that: [**Why is using “for…in” with array iteration such a bad idea?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea) Bascially when doing `for(u in users){`; Each time the loop is executed, `u` is filled with the name of another property that exists on the object until all properties have been returned. The returned properties are **both** those that exist on the object instance **and** those inherited through the prototype chain. Including objects from the prototype chain can lead to unexpected results.

Comment: @Wex: Additionally see [**For...in MDN Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). Bottom of `Description` Section has a comment on why for..in should not be used to iterate over an Array where index order is important.